# Ssh variable found in one python script to another python script and then execute the second script

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey guys I've got a problem.

I'm trying to send variable x that is found in script a to script b and then execute script b with that variable.

Example:

Script a

```
x = 10
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(x >> scriptB.py)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(./scriptB.py)
```

Script b

```
y = x
print y
```

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sys.argv. Which gives you a list of the items passed on the command line

```
x = 10
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("./scriptB.py " + str(x))
```

Script b

```
import sys

y = int(sys.argv[1])
print y
```

sys.argv will be a list that contains `['./scriptB.py', '10']` in this case.